# Is there a way to overwrite Blender's 16K limit for environment textures?

Tags: texturing

I'm rendering a planet in space. NASA has gorgeous equirectangular JPGs of the Milky Way up to 65K. I plugged in the 16K version and the render has blurry stars. To get them pin point I tried to load the 32K version. Render was cancelled with a note about the environment texture limit (16K) being exceeded. It there a way to overwrite this 16K limit? Thanks.

Comment: You will need close to a terabyte of memory for Blender to run and render that  size

Comment: The 32K texture is a 10Mb JPEG. How do you calculate 1Tb?

Comment: This is on your hard drive, in video memory image will be in raw data

Comment: It's not a exr or raw file, it's an 8-bit compressed JPEG. Could you elaborate? Or point me to a web resource where I can read up on this?

Comment: It doesn’t matter what size that texture file might have on your hard disk, as it will very likely be compressed one way or another. But the render engine needs access to uncompressed texture space. The memory consumption for that texture would be (if i'm not wrong) 8 bits* 4 Channels(RGBA) = 32 bits = 4 bytes ... a 32k is around 576 million pixels and so 4 bytes * 576,000,000 = 2,304,000,000 which is 2.04 petabyte.. Well, i was wrong is more than a terabyte.. If the calculation is wrong, please someone correct me

Comment: Sorry no: If an RGBA pixel is 32bits (4 bytes) then 4 bytes x 536 870 912 pixels (32768 x 16384px equirectangular environment texture) equals 2.14748365 gigabytes, not petabytes. A tough task for Blender to stuff that into 12Gb VRAM, but doable, I'd say.

Comment: Anyway, the question still stands: Is there a way to overwrite Blender's 16K limit for environment textures? And, if not, how can I get sharp stars in the background of my planet animation?

Comment: "If an RGBA pixel is 32bits"... RGBA pixel in Blender is 32bits PER channel. 4 channels - 32*4=128 bits per pixel... Anyway, memory is likely going to be a problem here. You can render only parts of the HDRI sphere with only parts of the texture you need. You can split the texture into a few parts and use it for a simple sphere split into matching parts and adjusted UVs with inverted normals and emission shader. You could probably use way lower resolution(like 4K) for reflections and lighting and the high resolution bits for background that is visible.

Comment: If I were you, I would just make my own star texture with a noise texture node. That would be more GPU-friendly. Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ezn9.png